# Calculating true positives and false positive for multi class classification model in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have a multi-class classification problem where by I have five different classes. I want to calculate TP and FP for my model. The code I have so far is:

```
def calculate(yTrue, yPred):
    TP,FP = 0,0

    for i in range(len(yPred)): 
        if yTrue[i]==yPred[i]==1:
           TP += 1
        if yPred[i]==1 and yTrue[i]!=yPred[i]:
           FP += 1

    return(TP, FP)
```

However, what I want to do now is join two classes to get total probability of a class. My classes are:

1. car
2. chair
3. bike
4. table
5. fan

So class 1 and class 3 belong to transport class and class 2, 4, and 5 belong to non-transport class.
I want to combine the p(car) and p(bike) to get total transport probability and I want to see if sum would be a useful value to use to distinguish true transport classes (regardless of their type) from false positives. That is I want to see what FP and TP look like with increasing confidence. For example,

1. number of TP and FP when p(bike) + p(car) > 90%
2. number of TP and FP when p(bike) + p(car) > 80%
3. number of TP and FP when p(bike) + p(car) > 70%

How can I modify my above code to take into account this slight change I want to incorporate?

Comment: You have yTrue and yPred separately for each of your classes? and what is their type (numpy array, list)?

Comment: yTrue and yPred are both numpy array and no in order to make confusion matrix I have one yTrue and one yPred. I didn't make it for separately for each of the classes.

Comment: you said you have 5 classes but your label only support 2 classs. What does your label look like?

Comment: It has five classes but now I just want to divide these 5 classes into 2 broad classes. Particularly I want to join the p(bike) and p(car) and see how FP and TP would change at different thresholds.